# iReport "cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base" error

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm working on Win XP with

- NetBeans 6.9.1
- iReport  4.1.3
- Liferay Portal 6.0.6 with Jboss 5.1.0 as Application Server
- jdk1.6.0_24

I'm doing a java portlet that generates a datasource ( a CustumDataSource of LinkedList of objects) for a report designed with iReport.

In my NetBeans project I added the following libraries:

- jasperreport-4.1.3.jar
- commons-digest-1.7.jar
- groovy-all-1.7.5.jar
- iText-2.1.7.jar

When i call the java code

```
...
jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperResource, jParams, jds);
....
```

I've the following error:

> ...
>   17:30:49,937 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot
>   assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStaticText
>   to field
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of
>   type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph 17:30:49,937 ERROR
>   [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
>   17:30:49,937 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1212)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:49,937 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStaticText to field
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of
>   type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph 2011-11-03
>   17:30:49,937 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)         at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
>   17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1952)
>   17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>   17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:49,937 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1212)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1952)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:49,968 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>   17:30:50,062 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479)
>   17:30:50,062 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextElement.readObject(JRBaseTextElement.java:1191)
>   17:30:50,062 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   17:30:50,078 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   17:30:50,078 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,062 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,062 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextElement.readObject(JRBaseTextElement.java:1191)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,062 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,078 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,078 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,156 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 2011-11-03
>   17:30:50,187 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)         at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,187 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,187 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,187 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   17:30:50,156 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 17:30:50,187 ERROR
>   [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
>   17:30:50,187 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
>   17:30:50,187 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   17:30:50,187 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   17:30:50,203 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,203 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,281 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593) 2011-11-03
>   17:30:50,281 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 2011-11-03
>   17:30:50,281 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,296 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,296 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 17:30:50,281 ERROR
>   [STDERR]         at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
>   17:30:50,281 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   17:30:50,281 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   17:30:50,296 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   17:30:50,296 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 17:30:50,296 ERROR
>   [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,296 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,375 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>   17:30:50,375 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
>   17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>   17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,390 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>   17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>   17:30:50,484 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>   17:30:50,500 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   17:30:50,578 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,500 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,578 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:192)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:580)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   it.robur.assistenza.GestActionERender.GestioneRender.gestRenderEseguiJasperReportDocumento(GestioneRender.java:286)
>   17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>   17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:192)
>   17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:580)
>   17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   it.robur.assistenza.GestActionERender.GestioneRender.gestRenderEseguiJasperReportDocumento(GestioneRender.java:286)
>   17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   it.robur.assistenza.Portlet.ProgettoAssistenza.doView(ProgettoAssistenza.java:289)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,593 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   it.robur.assistenza.Portlet.ProgettoAssistenza.doView(ProgettoAssistenza.java:289)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
>   17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
>   17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
>   17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
>   17:30:50,687 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
>   17:30:50,703 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,703 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,781 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
>   17:30:50,781 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
>   17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,796 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,890 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,890 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,890 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:50,906 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
>   17:30:50,890 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
>   17:30:50,890 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
>   17:30:50,890 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
>   17:30:50,906 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
>   17:30:50,906 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown
>   Source) 2011-11-03 17:30:50,906 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown
>   Source) 2011-11-03 17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>   17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>   17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>   17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>   17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,000 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>   17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
>   17:30:51,093 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>   17:30:51,109 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,109 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,203 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:3740)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,203 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1180)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,218 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:160)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,218 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:94)
>   17:30:51,203 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:3740)
>   17:30:51,203 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1180)
>   17:30:51,218 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:160)
>   17:30:51,218 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:94)
>   17:30:51,218 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:256)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,218 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:256)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:181)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown
>   Source) 2011-11-03 17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:181)
>   17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown
>   Source) 17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,312 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,406 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,406 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,421 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,421 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   17:30:51,406 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>   17:30:51,406 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>   17:30:51,421 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   17:30:51,421 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   17:30:51,421 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,421 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:370)
>   17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
>   17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>   17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
>   17:30:51,515 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:370)
>   17:30:51,531 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:629)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,531 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:629)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,609 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:232)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,609 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,625 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,625 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:153)
>   17:30:51,609 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:232)
>   17:30:51,609 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
>   17:30:51,625 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
>   17:30:51,625 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:153)
>   17:30:51,625 ERROR [STDERR]         at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,625 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,718 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,718 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,718 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:508)
>   2011-11-03 17:30:51,718 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:485)
>   ...

What am I doing wrong ?

TIA

Danilo Brembilla

Comment: I think that you have wrong expression in at least one static text fields or text fields. May be you pass the parameter with wrong type - for example String instead of Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a Static Text field in your report where you need to be using a Text Field. In iReport you can right-click the Static Text field and choose to convert it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I took your advice and I removed everything from the report (. Jrxml) and leave only a 'static field' in 'column header' and a 'static field' in 'the detail band.'
I then compiled to obtain the file (. Jasper) and run the java program.
The error has disappeared. Now I try to repopulate the entire report

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove Duplicate Jar...
2. Remove your Jasper report old jar and Add exactly jasper report library(Check Version is match or not)...
   you get jar from this path : 
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-4.7.0\ireport\modules\ext\jasperreports-4.7.0.jar"